# Disable buttons of android keypad

Tags: android, validation

i am trying to disable some keys of keypad in android. E.g when numeric keypad is opened. i want to disable buttons like +,- etc.
How can i do that.

Regards

Comment: did you solved it?if yes then post your answer to help other.And if you like any answer among them then please accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this detect + key if press then remove + from edittext like this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode==70){
        //do nothing ///
        Log.i("ss","dd");
        String str=edit.getText().toString().replace("+","");
        edit.setText(str);
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: hope it work//here in my emulator + key give key code 70 so i am comparing with 70

Answer (score 0):

you will need to define the edit text as a NoImeEditText in the xml (which is your custom edittext), then NoImeEditText et=(NoImeEditText) findViewById(R.id.itsId) should work.

```
public class NoImeEditText extends EditText {
  public EditTextEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
  super(context, attrs);     
  }      
  @Override      
  public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {   
  return false;     
  }        
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant disable + or - key from keypad. However you can restrict user from entering that key.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode==70){
        //do nothing ///
        Log.i("ss","dd");
        String str=edit.getText().toString().replace("+","");
        edit.setText(str);
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```